# alguien sabe como generar botones por medio de código en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo cierta informacion que traigo de una base de datos pero aveces esa informacion varia puede ser mucha o poca y quiero que aun lado de esa informacion me aparesca un boton pero no se como generarlo 
aun lado de cada casilla me gustaria que me aparecia un boton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de definir o crear un botón, la que pides tú, que es por código o también por interfaz gráfica.

Si buscas en la documentación de Android Studio tienes mucha información útil sobre cómo implementar botones y otras vistas desde código.

[Aquí tienes toda la información sobre la vista Botón](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button).

Crear botones mediante código suele ser útil cuando utilizas una app dinámica donde tienes que crear o eliminar botones según las necesidades de tu aplicación. Si solo quieres tener botones con una determinada función, te recomiendo que utilices el entorno gráfico para definir botones, ya que es más intuitivo y sencillo.

Con esta sentencia básica creamos un botón desde el código Java:

```
public Button (Context context)
```

Espero haberte ayudado a encontrar lo que buscabas, si tienes alguna duda en concreto, pregunta sin miedo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta de echo si tengo otra duda me gustaría poder comunicarme contigo seria de mucha utilidad

Comment: No te preocupes, para eso estamos. Considera votarme en positivo la respuesta o aceptarla como respuesta si consideras que ha solucionado tu duda.

Comment: como puedo comunicarme contigo seria increible el hacerlo